# Echoing a query doesn't work (returns "Resource id #18")

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

So I have this problem with php/mySql. I have the code shown below, and somehow it doesn't echo my the image (which is what is stored in the cell selected), but when I execute the **exact** same query in phpMyAdmin it suddenly works!

```
<?php 
  $logo_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'img_thumb_url' FROM rederijen WHERE id = '13';");
  //echo '<img src="' .$logo_query. '">';
  echo $logo_query;
?>
```

Instead of echoing me the URL to the image (lets just say it's "http://www.example.com/img/foo.jpg"), it returns me this:

```
Resource id #18
```

just as plain text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. You might want to read the [documentation for `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query). (Hint: it's a resource, you need apply some other functions to get the actual data)

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use mysql_query, use mysqli or PDO

Comment: You might also want to use mysqli, mysql is deprecated. see [mysqli](http://jp1.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: Another thing, take out the quotes around `img_thumb_url` in `SELECT 'img_thumb_url'` to be `SELECT img_thumb_url ...` or use backticks instead. @Fennoman

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to echo out a resource. What you're wanting to do is echo out the result, which you can do by first calling `mysql_fetch_row`:

```
<?php 
  $logo_query = mysql_query("SELECT `img_thumb_url` FROM rederijen WHERE id = '13';");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($logo_query);
  // you now have the result in an array, so to echo out 'img_thumb_url' we'll echo out the first key in the array
  echo $row[0];
?>
```

Comment: `select 'img_thumb_url'` will return that actual string. Maybe a typo?

Comment: You're right that I had a typo, but you're wrong in that `select 'img_thumb_url'` returns a string. From the documentation: 'Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.'. Edited my answer to use numeric keys instead of named keys.

Comment: No, I mean't that the `select 'img_thumb_url'` will return the string  `img_thumb_url` instead of the actual data from the column. :)

Comment: You may be correct, I was actually thinking those were backticks.

Comment: hence the `maybe a typo?`. on another note, you might be thinking I was the one who down-voted this, t'was not me.

Comment: Updated my answer to use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>   www.php.net/mysql_query

You should try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($logo_query)) {
    echo $row['img_thumb_url'];
}
```

Of course you should read more about mysql extension, and maybe switch to mysqli or PDO.